# Why isn't horizontal scroll showing in my html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add both horizontal and vertical scroll in table.

**Code :**

```css
    #employee_details{
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:15em;
      left:20em;
      width:85em;
      height: 20em;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    #emp{
      height: 20em;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
      width: 40em;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="emp"><table id="employee_details" border="2"></table></div>
```

But in my output, I am getting only the vertical scroll in my table, not the horizontal scroll.

How do I fix this?

Please help me.

Comment: add `overflow: scroll;` to have both horizontal and vertical scroll

Comment: remove all styles from the table, especially the position absolute and display block

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to your parent div `#emp`

```css
#emp {
  height: 20em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 40em;
  position: relative;
}

#employee_details {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15em;
  left: 20em;
  width: 85em;
  height: 20em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="emp">
  <table id="employee_details" border="2"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.emp {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.employee_details {
  min-width: rem-calc(640);
}
```

```html
<div id="emp">
<table id="employee_details" border="2">
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The table is having both vertical and horizontal scrolls. if you want to see you can reduce the width and height of the table("#employee_details").